# How to get service instance's endpoint uri?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm working on a wcf service and I have the need for it to figure out it's own endpoint address (pref. in the constructor). 
Is this possible and if so, could anyone point me to the right direction? The service is hosted on IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var uri = OperationContext
    .Current
    .EndpointDispatcher
    .EndpointAddress
    .Uri;
```

Comment: I tried this, but it throws an NullReferenceException (OperationContext.Current is apparently null for some reason).
Strangely enough, it seems to work on a self hosted application... Any suggestions?

Comment: Where are you running this code? During the execution of an operation?

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of Endpoints for a Service you would do the following:

//_Service is of type  System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost

ServiceEndpointCollection endPoints_ = _Service.Description.Endpoints;